# Django Redirect to previous view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a button on page x and page y that redirects to page z. 
On page z, I have a form that needs filling out. Upon saving, I want to redirect to page x or y (whichever one I was on initially).

Normally, you use "redirect" in the view, and specify the page you want to redirect to. But what would you do in a case like this?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use GET parameters to track from which page you arrived to page z. So when you are arriving normally to page z we remember from which page we came. When you are processing the form on page z, we use that previously saved information to redirect. So:

The button/link on page y should include a parameter whose value is the current URL:

```
<a href="/page_z/?from={{ request.path|urlencode }}" />go to form</a>
```

Then in page_z's view you can pass this onto the template:

```
def page_z_view(self, request):
    ...
    return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', { 'from' : request.GET.get('from', None) })
```

and in your form template:

```
<form action="{% if from %}?next={{ from }}{% endif %}" />
...
```

So now the form - when submitted - will pass on a `next` parameter that indicates where to return to once the form is successfully submitted. We need to revist the view to perform this:

```
def page_z_view(self, request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Do all the form stuff
        next = request.GET.get('next', None)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
    return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', { 'from' : request.GET.get('from', None)}
```

Comment: so my button on page y should be something like this:

<input type="button" value="Add" onClick="location.href='/page_z?from=%2Fpage_y'">

? For some reason that isn't working. For one, my form no longer saves even though the "next" is under my if form valid.. And I am being redirected to the original welcome page.. although that's the wrong page to begin with.. i dont even kno where it got that from lol..

Comment: I've updated the answer - I had put in an extra / in the `<form action ...`. There are two stages here. One when you initially arrive on the empty form page and the URL from which you arrived is embedded in the `<form action=...` to be picked up in the second stage - when the form is actually submitted. It's kinda hard to explain! Just remember that your `view_z` is getting executed two times - first when arriving, second when submitting

Comment: thank you :) only one quick correction: in your <form action="..... it is {% endif %} not endform.. I'm sure it's just a typo though! well done! and thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Django request knows what the page the user came from is:

```
previous_page = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
```

It will contain something like:

```
>>> print(previous_page)
'http://www.myserver.com/myApp/z'
```

Hence you know where you came from (warning, treat it as unsafe data and verify it thoroughly, it might even contain malicious data) and use the information.

First you pass it to template as

```
data = {
    ...,
    # also indicate, that saved data are valid and user can leave
    'previous_page': previous_page,
}
```

Render the page z.html

```
return render(request, 'myApp/z.html', data)
```

And in the template of the page z, you add the meta-refresh tag to the . It will cause that once the form is saved and page loaded, user will be redirected redirected back automatically:

```
{% if form_is_saved and previous_page %}<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url={{ previous_page }}" />{% endif %}
```

This has the advantage, that form is saved by the page z.html, where it is filled and you do not need to handle it by pages x and y (this is the only way to do it if pages x and y are outside of your Django app).

Answer (score -3):

Store information about the pages your user has been visiting, so you can retrieve it later. Probably the best place to do that is in the session.