# Remember which view you came from after you do a POST on current view

Tags: django, forms, redirect, web, get

I know that it is possible to know which view you came from using a GET parameter. Ref: [Django Redirect to previous view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350990/django-redirect-to-previous-view). However, if you do a POST on the current view, this information gets wiped.

For my purpose I have a django application where you can get to the same view, that has a form and a back button, from multiple destinations. Everything works fine until you submit the form, and then gets redirected to the same view without any information regarding where you came from in the beginning.

Please comment if any examples is needed to understand my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when you use the `POST` method the `GET` parameters are still available to you:

```
<form action="{% if from %}?next={{ from }}{% endif %}" method="POST" />
```

And then in the view:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        ...
        next_url = request.GET.get('next')
    ...
```

Moreover, you can omit the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag so you don't have to pass the `from` context variable to the template:

```
<form method="POST" />
```

In this case the `GET` parameters will be "saved" automatically between requests.