# Django: redirect user two pages back

Tags: python, html, django

I have a list of multiple objects from my database (named "plp's"), arranged in a table. Next to each "plp" element I have a button "Edit" to modify that particular entry.

Next, I redirect the user to a new url, where I pass the id of that "plp", and show the form to edit it, with a "save" button.

After pressing the "save", which is request.POST, I want to redirect the user back to the first url, with the list of all the "plp" objects in one list. That means to the site, where he first pressed "Edit".

Can I somehow save the url of where the "Edit" was clicked, and pass it to my views.py?

Thank you

```
listdns.html:
<td>
<a href='{% url "plpuredi" plp_id=pos.id %}' class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Uredi</a>
</td>
```

urls.py:

```
rl(r'^(?P<plp_id>\d+)/uredi$', plp_list_uredi,name="plpuredi")
```

views.py:

```
def plp_list_uredi(request, plp_id=None):
moj_plp=PLPPostavka.objects.get(id=plp_id)
form=PLPPostavkaForm(request.POST or None,request=request,dns=moj_plp.dns, instance=moj_plp)
context ={
    'plp':moj_plp,
    'form':form,
}
if request.POST:
    if form.is_valid():
        plp = form.save()
        return redirect(request.path)
return render(request, "plp_pos/uredi.html",context)
```

uredi.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="box">
<div class="box-header">
    <h4 class="box-title">
       Urejanje PLP Postavke
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-2 control-label detail">{{ field.label }}</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
{% if field|field_type == "datefield" %}
  {% render_field field class+="form-control dateinput" %}
{% else %}
  {% render_field field class+="form-control" %}
{% endif %}       
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="box-footer">
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
        <input type="submit" value="Shrani" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide your models.py, urls.py and views.py

Comment: Include your code inside the post please

Comment: i think you just need to change line : `return redirect(request.path)` and use httpredirect to url you want to redirect to

Comment: I do the redirect(request.path) just so I don't get an error when save is called.

Comment: I solved the problem using this solution: [Django Redirect to previous view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350990/django-redirect-to-previous-view)

Answer (score 1):

Don't you only have 1 page to edit all the elements? Then you could perhaps hardcode the link e.g.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(my_edit_url)
```

If this doesn't work and you need to go 2 pages back take a look at this post:
[How to redirect to previous page in Django after POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796195/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-django-after-post-request/35796559#35796559)